# Need to define a variable's value from the ajax returned response message

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am submitting a form via ajax and would like to hide a particular div within the html as defined by the returned success message.  All is working except for the hide part which  works fine if I directly write in the div's id.  But I can't get it working when I try using data.message to define the particular div id (ie "4610").  I'm confident that the success message is correct as I see it displayed properly in the console.  Thanks! - Brian

```
 // using the done promise callback
        .done(function(data) {

        if (data.success) {
            // success.
            // hide form container
            $("#data.message").hide();
           }
         }
```

Comment: Don't pass `data.success` - learn about HTTP status codes instead. Also, don't abuse selectors like that - divs should not have numeric ids like that, learn about arrays, objects and data structure and have a backing model for your data. You are querying your presentation layer here where what you need is an array.

Answer (score 0):

If your data.message contains your id, you have to concat strings like this ..

```
 $("#"+data.message).hide(); // instead of $("#data.message").hide();
```

Comment: what if `data.message` its `undefined` ?

Comment: What if the id needs escaping?

Comment: Obviously if the data comming from the server needs some escaping process then escape it `:/`. Feel free to implement all kind of protection to prevent such cases ... the original problem here was a string interpretation matter. Since you did not post 'data' structure, one might guess that you would handle escaping/parsing process on your own ..

Comment: Thank you FOObar.  I wasn't clear about how to correctly concat the strings.  That works perfectly.  On the bigger topic, as pointed out by Benjamin Gruenbaum, I will eventually rewrite the code with a proper n-tier architecture...just have a time crunch right now.  Thanks again!

Comment: you're welcome ! Mind to set this thread as solved by choosing an answer as your solution `;)`